# How come when I change the height of this div, it "overlaps" the div below it?

Tags: css, html, templates

How do i make it so that as the first div expands...the lower div will automatically go lower, due to the height of the first div now is larger?

Is this display? Or Position?

Comment: please post your css and html and then we can help.

Comment: Seems you think everybody is a mind-reader or has bothered to hack into your computer to actually see this code you're talking around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use floating elements. This will ensure that the container beneath will always stay below the top container depending on where the top one ends. I.e.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<div style="height:250; width:250px; background-color:red; float:left;"> TOP </div>
<div style="height:250; width:250px; background-color:blue; float:left; clear:left;"> BOTTOM </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you download firebug and tweak the CSS of your page to make it the way you want it - start playing around with the display attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use floats. Float the top one left (or right). Set the bottom one to clear left (or right).

Comment: Or `clear: both;` presuming that he *wants* the second div to be below the first. =)

Comment: True! I'm assuming the first div is the content div, therefore it's the top div moving the bottom one...